# Fixing the line between my images in parallax

Tags: html, css, parallax

I am trying to create a parallax effect with my images as well as a starting video.

However, there is some sort of spacing or padding between each image. How can I get rid of the spacing?

[image: Image of the issue]

This is the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HomePage</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HomPage.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Pinyon+Script" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

<div class="parallax-one">
  <h1> Welcome </h1>
  <p>Infusing my passion of the arts and love of programing to create something unique</p>
  <div class="fullscreen-bg">
  <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
      <source src="lighthouse.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
</div>



<div class="parallax-two">
  <h2>BUILD YOUR DREAMS</h2>
  <p>A polymath full stack developer and a bussiness background.
  With a passion for developing.</p>
</div>
```

This is my CSS so far:

```
  *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
body , html{
    height:100%;
    /*background-image: url("Index.jpg");*/

}


.parallax-one {
  /*background-image: url("bviex5lwf3s-ng.jpg");*/
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.parallax-two {
    background-image: url("0lu4vo5ifpm-greg-rakozy.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.parallax-three {
    background-image: url("ln_g3qa8ohg-patrick-mcmanaman.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.parallax-four{
    background-image: url("mwhklqgvzck-juskteez-vu.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.parallax-five{
    background-image: url("19._caron_massacre_under_the_triumvirate_2800x1232.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

}

.fullscreen-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


p{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;

}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 200px;
    padding-top: 300px;


}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
    padding-top: 100px;


}
```

Comment: Can you host your images somewhere and create a working demo for us please?

Comment: And your relevent HTML will be helpful

Comment: I also added the HTML thank you for the help.

Comment: for some reason the photos do not connect to one another and there is space which is the body or html